# Help with simplifying a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can somebody explain to me how to get to the simplification of the following equation (found by wolfram alpha, see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify%20-(x%27(t)%5E2*x%27%27(t))%2F(1%2Bx%27(t)%5E2)%5E(3%2F2)%2Bx%27%27(t)%2Fsqrt(1%2Bx%27(t)%5E2)))? It seems I'm missing something ;).

$$ -\frac{\dot x(t)^2\ddot x(t)}{(1+\dot x(t)^2)^{3/2}}+ \frac{\ddot x(t)}{\sqrt(1+\dot x(t)^2}= \frac{\ddot x(t)}{(\dot x(t)^2+1)^{3/2}} $$

Comment: It seems that your post is missing the actual question. (Please typeset it using MathJax instead of posting URLs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to simplify

$$\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x'(t)^2+1}}-\frac{x'(t)^2}{\left(x'(t)^2+1\right)^{3/2}}\right) x''(t)$$

For the expression in the parenthesis, we have a common denominator of $\left(x'(t)^2+1\right)^{3/2}$, so get

$$\left(\frac{x'(t)^2+1}{\left(x'(t)^2+1\right)^{3/2}} - \dfrac{x'(t)^2}{\left(x'(t)^2+1\right)^{3/2}}\right) x''(t)$$

The result follows.